# Modifying a const qualified object through a pointer

Tags: c

The following code compiles and runs as I expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
      const char        C1 = '1';
      char const        C2 = '3';

      printf("%c %c", C1, C2);

      char *pC1 = &C1; *pC1 = 'H';
      char *pC2 = &C2; *pC2 = 'o';

      printf("%c %c", C1, C2);

      return 0;
}
```

This code invokes undefined behaviour?

Comment: This code **won't** compile if you enable warnings/errors: http://ideone.com/df4xiC

Comment: At the end of the day, you're still modifying something that's `const`. Yes, this is UB.

Comment: This code *must* give you a diagnostic, because `&C1` and `pC1` are not compatible. In C, diagnostics are errors.

Comment: "*The following code compiles and runs correctly.*" should be "**The following code compiles and runs as I expected.**". There is no "*correctly*" possible mixed with UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this code invokes undefined behavior. According to C standard,

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.